# Nginx not forwarding reason phrase

Tags: http, nginx, http2, http-1.1

I am hosting my Django app with Gunicorn. What happen is as follow

A sample response from Django would be as follow

```py
@require_http_methods(['POST'])
def register(request):

    body = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))

    try:
        email = body['email']
    except:
        return HttpResponse(status=400, reason="Email must be provided.")
```

During the development, the Django app are run with command `python manage.py runserver` and have no issue at all with it. It always response with

`400 Email must be provided`

However, in the production environment, it is hosted as follow

***Procfile***

```
web: gunicorn app.wsgi
release: python manage.py migrate
```

***wsgi.py***

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'app.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Yet, when making a request, the response left as below.

`400`

What am I missing out to not letting the reason being forwarded properly?

****Edit 1***

There is also a different between production and development, which is in production environment, gunicorn live behind a nginx where development don't. Could the problem cause by Nginx not forwarding local reason phase, and if yes, is it possible to change it?

****Edit 2***

Below is my nginx.conf

```
server {
  listen      [::]:80;
  listen      80;
  server_name api.app.com; 
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/app-access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/app-error.log;

  return 301 https://$host:443$request_uri;

}

server {
  listen      [::]:443 ssl http2;
  listen      443 ssl http2;

  server_name api.app.com; 
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/app-access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/app-error.log;

  ssl_certificate           /home/dokku/app/tls/server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key       /home/dokku/app/tls/server.key;
  ssl_protocols             TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

  keepalive_timeout   70;


  location    / {

    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length  1100;
    gzip_buffers  4 32k;
    gzip_types    text/css text/javascript text/xml text/plain text/x-component application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json application/xml  application/rss+xml font/truetype application/x-font-ttf font/opentype application/vnd.ms-fontobject image/svg+xml;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level  6;

    proxy_pass  http://app-5000;


    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Request-Start $msec;
  }
  include /home/dokku/app/nginx.conf.d/*.conf;

  error_page 400 401 402 403 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 420 422 423 424 426 428 429 431 444 449 450 451 /400-error.html;
  location /400-error.html {
    root /var/lib/dokku/data/nginx-vhosts/dokku-errors;
    internal;
  }

  error_page 404 /404-error.html;
  location /404-error.html {
    root /var/lib/dokku/data/nginx-vhosts/dokku-errors;
    internal;
  }

  error_page 500 501 503 504 505 506 507 508 509 510 511 /500-error.html;
  location /500-error.html {
    root /var/lib/dokku/data/nginx-vhosts/dokku-errors;
    internal;
  }

  error_page 502 /502-error.html;
  location /502-error.html {
    root /var/lib/dokku/data/nginx-vhosts/dokku-errors;
    internal;
  }
}

upstream app-5000 {

  server 172.17.0.8:5000;
}
```

Comment: are you getting 400 for all the urls or only for that particular url?

Comment: It was suppose to get 400, which is intended, but the problem is the reason_phrase are not presented.

Comment: Can you also show your nginx configuration?

Comment: @DanielRoseman due to nginx.conf being too long, I had edited the post and added it there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that the reason phrase are not being forwarded is due to nginx listening to http2. Http2 does away the reason phrase from http1.1, and the way to solve it will be forcing nginx to listen to http1.1.

***nginx.conf***

```
...

server {
  listen      [::]:443 ssl;
  listen      443 ssl;

  server_name api.app.com; 
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/app-access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/app-error.log;

...
```

This will solve the problem of reason phrase not being forwarded.